# Is there any easy way to run an SSIS package in a "demo" mode?

Tags: ssis

I realise this would be massively complex under the hood in SSIS.....

But is there a way to run a SSIS package in Visual Studio in a demo mode, that does not alter any data. Only runs a "simulation"?

I can imagine this would be very complex under the hood - running all sorts of transactions and rolling them back reliably.

But other microsoft tools such as MSDeploy are able to simulate (but admittedly it would be much simpler), so I'm hoping (I think I might be asking too much), that SSIS might have a similar feature

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no demo feature in SSIS.  To do what you want, you'd be best to have a script that you run after the package execution to restore the database to it's original state.  Or to restore a stable backup of the database.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing built in to SSIS that will run a package as a simulation.